# Erro de php com mysql e mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, conexão

Eu sou meio novo em programação e estou com uma dificuldade, estava programando um site e rodava ele no wampserver, porém de um tempo para cá atualizei a versão do wamp e os comandos MYSQL do php passaram a parar de funcionar, funciona só quando mudo os comandos para MYSQLI e mesmo assim ainda ta dando mtos erros `mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in ./.../.....` ou `mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in` em todo select que usava, por exemplo:

```
$variavel = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5") or die(mysqli_error());
```

a parte de conexão com o banco esta assim:

```
    header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
    $servidor = "...";
    $usuarioServidor = "...";
    $senhaServidor = "...";
    $nomeBD = "...";

    $conectar = @mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuarioServidor,$senhaServidor) or die ("Não foi possível acessar o servidor");
    $selesionarBD = @mysqli_select_db($nomeBD,$conectar) or die (mysqli_error());
```

lembrando que quando coloco MYSQL não funciona, só com MYSQLI

Por que os comandos MYSQL não estão funcionando mais e porque os MYSQLI estão dando erro?

Answer (score 2):

Quando você utiliza a função [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php), você **deve** passar dois atributos: O *resource* e a *query*.

```
if (!mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM tabela")) {
    die(mysqli_error($conectar));
}
```

Já na função [mysqli_error](http://br.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), você **deve** passar apenas o atributo *resource*.

Esse atributo permite à função identificar qual é a conexão, qual o banco de dados está selecionado etc.

*Quando você trabalha com Orientação a Objetos, isso não é necessário.*

Comment: Bom, respondeu antes então apaguei minha resposta +1, mysql está obsoleto apartir da versão 5.5.0 do php use mysqli. Pagina de documentação do mysqli : https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

Alessandro Pardo, você deve seguir a documentação do php conforme a extensão utilizada [Extensão MySQL Melhorada](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)

A parte da consulta deve ficar assim:

```
$variavel = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5") or die(mysqli_error($conectar));
```

A parte de código do banco de dados deve ficar assim:

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
$servidor = "...";
$usuarioServidor = "...";
$senhaServidor = "...";
$nomeBD = "...";

$conectar = @mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuarioServidor,$senhaServidor,$nomeBD) or die ("Não foi possível acessar o servidor");
$selesionarBD = @mysqli_select_db($conectar, $nomeBD) or die (mysqli_error($conectar));
```